# Problem computing partial derivatives with GradientTape() in TensorFlow2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

i have problems in the computation of gradients using automatic differentiation in TensorFlow. Basically i want to create a neural network which has just one output-value f and get an input of two values (x,t). The network should act like a mathematical function, so in this case f(x,t) where x and t are the input-variables and i want to compute partial derivatives, for example `df_dx, d2f/dx2` or `df_dt`. I need those partial derivatives later for a specific loss-function.
Here is my simplified code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import Model


class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = Flatten(input_shape=(2, 1))
        self.d1 = Dense(28)
        self.f = Dense(1)

    def call(self, y):
        y = self.flatten(y)
        y = self.d1(y)
        y = self.f(y)
        return y

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #inp contains the input-variables (x,t)
    inp = np.random.rand(1,2,1)
    inp_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(inp, np.float32)   

    #Create a Model
    model = MyModel()

    #Here comes the important part:
    x = inp_tf[0][0]
    t = inp_tf[0][1]

    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch(inp_tf[0][0])
        tape.watch(inp_tf)
        f = model(inp_tf)

    df_dx = tape.gradient(f, inp_tf[0][0])  #Derivative df_dx
    grad_f = tape.gradient(f, inp_tf)

    tf.print(f)         #--> [[-0.0968768075]]
    tf.print(df_dx)     #--> None
    tf.print(grad_f)    #--> [[[0.284864038]
                        #      [-0.243642956]]]
```

What i expected was that i get `df_dx = [0.284864038]` (the first component of grad_f), but it results in `None`. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to get partial derivatives of f to only one input-variable?
2. If yes: What i have to change in my code that the computation df_dx doesn't result `None`?

What i think could do is to modify the architecture of the `class MyModel` that i use two different Inputlayer (one for x and one for t) so that i can call the model like `f = model(x,t)` but that seems unnatural for me and i think there should be an easier way.

---

Another point is that i don't get an Error when i change the input_shape of the Flattenlayer for example to `self.flatten = Flatten(input_shape=(5,1)` but my inputvector has shape(1,2,1), so i expect to get an error but that's not the case, why? I'm grateful for your help :)

---

I use the following configurations:

- Visual Studio Code with Python-Extension as IDE
- Python-Version: 3.7.6
- TensorFlow-Version: 2.1.0
- Keras-Version: 2.2.4-tf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you do `inp_tf[0][0]` or `inp_tf[0][1]` you are creating a new tensor, but that new tensor is not used as input to your model, `inp_tf` is. Even if `inp_tf[0][0]` if part of `inp_tf`, from the point of view of TensorFlow there is no computation graph between your newly created `inp_tf[0][0]` and `f`, hence there is no gradient. You have to compute the gradient with respect to `inp_tf` and then take the parts of the gradient that you want from there.

In addition to that, as shown in the documentation of [`tf.GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape), you can use nested tapes to compute second order derivatives. And, if you use the [`jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian), you can avoid using `persistent=True`, which is better for performance. Here is how it could work in your example (I changed the layer activation functions to `sigmoid`, as the default linear activation would not have a second order derivative).

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import Model

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = Flatten(input_shape=(2, 1))
        self.d1 = Dense(28, activation='sigmoid')
        self.f = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, y):
        y = self.flatten(y)
        y = self.d1(y)
        y = self.f(y)
        return y

np.random.seed(0)
inp = np.random.rand(1, 2, 1)
inp_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(inp, np.float32)
model = MyModel()
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(inp_tf)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        tape2.watch(inp_tf)
        f = model(inp_tf)
    grad_f = tape2.gradient(f, inp_tf)
    df_dx = grad_f[0, 0]
    df_dt = grad_f[0, 1]
j = tape.jacobian(grad_f, inp_tf)
d2f_dx2 = j[0, 0, :, 0, 0]
d2f_dyx = j[0, 0, :, 0, 1]
d2f_dy2 = j[0, 1, :, 0, 1]
d2f_dxy = j[0, 1, :, 0, 0]

tf.print(df_dx)
# [0.0104712956]
tf.print(df_dt)
# [-0.00301733566]
tf.print(d2f_dx2)
# [[-0.000243180315]]
tf.print(d2f_dyx)
# [[-0.000740956515]]
tf.print(d2f_dy2)
# [[1.49392872e-05]]
tf.print(d2f_dxy)
# [[-0.000740956573]]
```